# IndexError: index 26 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 26

Tags: python

I can't show the 'Z' because of index error.
before i have to make an cnn architecture with vgg-19, dense 26.
because the classes on google drive is 26 classes (A-Z)

```
#A= io.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Proyek Akhir/datasetBISINDO/BISINDO Sign Language/X/IMG_1047.JPG') #X
#A= io.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Proyek Akhir/datasetBISINDO/BISINDO Sign Language/Y/IMG_1057.JPG') #Y
A= io.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Proyek Akhir/datasetBISINDO/BISINDO Sign Language/Z/IMG_1067.JPG') #Z

B= cv2.resize(A, (64, 64))
print(B.shape)
print(A.shape)

#plt.subplot(1, 2, 1),plt.imshow(A), plt.title("Original"), plt.axis('off')
#plt.subplot(1, 2, 2),plt.imshow(B), plt.title("Reshape"), plt.axis('off')
#===================================================
#img = image.load_img(A,target_size=(224,224))

img=B
img = np.asarray(img)
plt.imshow(img),plt.title("Predikted Result"), plt.axis('off')
img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
from keras.models import load_model
saved_model = load_model(r"/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/VGG19PAbagas.h5")
output = saved_model.predict(img)
if output[0][0] > output[0][1]:
  print("A")
```

cont,

```
  print('X')
elif output[0][24] > output[0][25]:
  print('Y')
elif output[0][25] > output[0][26]:
  print('Z')
else:
  print('Tidak Terdefinisi')
```

the traceback,

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-33700d0a695d> in <module>()
    106 elif output[0][24] > output[0][25]:
    107   print('Y')
--> 108 elif output[0][25] > output[0][26]:
    109   print('Z')
    110 else:
```

this is, how i made the vgg file

```
model = vgg.output
model = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()(model)
model = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(model)
model = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512,activation='relu')(model)
model = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.25)(model)
model = tf.keras.layers.Dense(26,activation='softmax')(model)#Ganti angka sesuai jumlah kelas
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=vgg.input, outputs = model)
```

and, total classes in my drive is 26. (A-Z), how can i made it to count until 27th? because i need to show the 'Z' element

Comment: Indexing starts at `0`, so using index `26` would translate to trying to get the 27th value of a 26-value list.

Comment: where i should to change that index?

Comment: Delete `elif output[0][25] > output[0][26]`? - the Traceback should tell you which line is the culprit. When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to compare index 25 for Z to?  What you're asking for doesn't make any sense.

Comment: i made a translation system, and i need to show the Z element. but it can't because the index is out of bounds

Comment: Each `if` statement compares the value for one letter against the value for the next letter.  There is no next letter after Z.  What should you compare against instead?

Comment: ow, i'm sorry its cropped. theres
else:
  print ('Tidak Terdefinisi')

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use index 26 and it is giving you the error, it is because the indexing starts at 0 and the program basically is trying to give you the 27th element, which is'nt present. So, try returning the 25th index, it would give you the 26th character.

Comment: but, i need all of these elements (A-Z). how can i?

Comment: Its the same, way, suppose there is an array {1, 2, 3, 4}. The indexes start from 0 and go till 3. So use the indexes from 0 to 3 to print them out.